# Converting a jQuery method to string

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently I am recording all the changes made by Jquery as this:

```
$.fn.meChangeText = function ($text,$textpath) {
    $(this).html($text);
        //I am storing the code block here storing in a string
    $codeblock = $codeblock + "\n" + 
                     "$(\"" + $textpath + "\").html(\"" + $text + "\");"

};
```

Is there another way where I can convert $(this).html($text) function to a string? This means let say I am changing:

```
    $("#id1").text("I am changing");
```

I want it to be in a string as this:

```
 var code = "$(\"#id1\").text(\"I am changing\");"
```

### Update

Why am I doing this?

This is because I want to store all the changes made in a database.

Comment: Can you explain more about converting to string?

Comment: Why do you need it? because if its for debugging purposes, you'll be better off with 'console.log'

Comment: It is not for debugging purpose. It is for me to store the edits. I want to execute the codes that are stored in the string when a user needs to see the changes that he has made.

Comment: The reason I need this because, I am storing the Jquery code block in the database.

Comment: It's not trivial to serialize DOM elements. What if an element does not have an ID? You really should edit your question and provide a proper description of what you are trying to do and why (with a better example).

Comment: You shouldn't store code the in the DB. I would store change sets, containing some way to identify the changed element and the value that was changed. For example, encoded as JSON: `{"element": "#id1", "content": "I am changing"}`. But as I already said, finding a way to uniquely identify an element is difficult if it doesn't have an ID. One way would to compute the elements XPath from the root.

Comment: I understand the concerns and I am already using the xpath. As said before, I want to change not just the content but even the look and feel. So I need to store the exact JQuery codes that does the changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my solution and I believe that there is a better solution out there as compared to mine:

```
 $.fn.ChangeText = function ($text,$textpath) {
          $(this).html($text); //change the textbox
          $temp = '$(this).html($text);'; //make a copy of the change in String
          $temp = $temp.replace("this",'\"'+$textpath+'\"');
          $temp = $temp.replace("$text",'\"'+$text+ '\"');
          $data.code = $data.code + $data.code;
};
```

However the above solution does not convert the codeblock to String but "hard cording" the method signature as String. So to convert this method signature as String `$(this).html($text); I had to "hardcode" the method signature as String as such`$temp = '$(this).html($text);';`.

If you have a better solution, please share so that others can benefit.

Answer (score 4):

Just store texts in an array:

```
history = {}

$.fn.meChangeText = function (text, textpath) {
    if(!history[textpath])    
        history[textpath] = [];
    history[textpath].push($(textpath).html());
    $(textpath).html(text)
})
```

and the undo function will be like this:

```
$.fn.undo = function (textpath) {
    if(!history[textpath])    
        return
    $(textpath).html(history[textpath].pop());
})
```

Comment: The above example is just a text example. It has to be stored in a text string as I will also be changing the css of an element. The above question was simplified. I am not looking at storing the text but storing the code block.

Comment: @madi: well, this sounds like [XY problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341) to me. Metaprogramming and code generation is almost never a solution.

Comment: I have updated my question. And I hope that I made it clear. The reason is because I want to store all the edits as a code block so that I can run the script when user reverts back to a certain revision.